# MONTY HALL SIMULATION: Why are these 2 versions of my code giving different output?

Tags: python, loops, random, conditional-statements

**Before showing two different versions for my simulation of the Monty Hall problem:**

+If this is the first time you heard about the Monty Hall problem before, you can find it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?fbclid=IwAR35Ar6wrCtU-kxvqhFEvYm1ERhqI24iSzz5nZOwXfhBF1iPZn6ZlNaO1Vw&v=iBdjqtR2iK4&feature=youtu.be

or

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

The Monty Hall problem is a famous conundrum in probability which takes the form of a hypothetical game show. The contestant is presented with three doors; behind one is a car and behind each of the other two is a goat. The contestant picks a door and then the gameshow host opens a different door to reveal a goat. The host knows which door conceals the car. The contestant is then invited to switch to the other closed door or stick with their initial choice.

Perhaps counter-intuitively, the best strategy for winning the car is to switch, as demonstrated by the following simulation.

+**Here is a correct sample code of simulating the problem**: https://matthew-brett.github.io/dsfe/chapters/extra/monty_hall_lists

**So, I wrote 2 different versions of my own to simulate the problem.**

The output of my program is the number of times the contestant won a car when they choose to switch for every case.

The first version, which gives the right output (~67):

```
import random
count = 0
n = 100
##n is number of test case
i = 0
while i<n:
  list1 = ["goat","goat","goat"]
  prize = random.randint(0,2)
  list1[prize] = "Car"
  choose = random.randint(0,2)
  while True:
    opendoor = random.randint(0,2)
    if (opendoor!=choose and list1[opendoor]!="Car"):
      break
  i+=1
  choose = 3- opendoor - choose
  if list1[choose]=="Car":
    count+=1
print(count)
```

The second version, which gives the wrong output (~50):

```
import random
count = 0
n = 100
##n is number of test case
i = 0
while i<n:
  list1 = ["goat","goat","goat"]
  prize = random.randint(0,2)
  list1[prize] = "Car"
  choose = random.randint(0,2)
  while True:
    opendoor = random.randint(0,2)
    if (opendoor!=choose):
      break
  if (list1[opendoor]!="Car"):
    i+=1
    choose=3-opendoor-choose
    if list1[choose]=="Car":
      count+=1
print(count)
```

Basically, they generate the same amount of loop, and all the numbers are also randomly generated. But I don't understand why the outputs are so different.

I know that the second program would eliminate all the cases where `list1[open]=="Car"`. However, it still generates a new loop. I know that it could affect the result. The answer that I am looking for is a mathematical explanation of this problem.

So, once again. Can you please mathematically or logically explain why this occurs?

Comment: In your second case, you don't appear to prevent opening the door with the car in it. If you fix that, does that address the issue?

Comment: btw, don't use `open` as the name of a variable. It is already used as a built-in.

Comment: Ok, so I would change to "opendoor" instead, but here is my concern:

I know that the second program would eliminate all the cases where list1[open]=="Car". However, it still generates a new loop. I know that it could affect the result. The answer that I am looking for is a mathematical explanation of this problem.

So, once again. Can you please mathematically or logically explain why this occurs?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just trace out every possible execution? This is something that could be solved on paper.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you only wanted to make one valid trial, which means that your variable i must be equal to 1.

In the first code, if in the first selection the chosen door has a goat, it is guaranteed that the opened door will be which has the other goat and so the game will be counted as a valid one, adding also a +1 to the switching strategy.

In the second code, if in the first selection the chosen door has a goat, the game has the potential to be discarded because the opened door could have the car. So, choosing a goat door at first does not imply a +1 to the switching strategy. It could still happen that the game must be repeated and so in the new trial you get the car door in the first selection, which is a game where staying wins. So, you added ways to win by staying, that were eliminated from the ones to win by switching.

When you make multiple attempts of this, you end discarding some games in which you would have won by switching and you replace them with games in which you win by staying. You substract numbers to a strategy and add them to the other.